# Android Studio creates blank layout xml file on create new resource xml file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am developing my project in Android Studio. While creating `ListView` application, I am trying to create a new layout `.xml` file for `list_item_row`

What I did is right click on `/res/layout` then `LayoutResourceFile` then given the name.
But it generates a blank file.
Even the root node is not available, just a blank screen.

The same thing happening while creating new menu xml file.

What is the problem in the Android Studio and how can I rectify it?

[image]

[image]

Hope now my questions is clear.

Comment: are you looking at preview? or xml code? which one is blank?

Comment: invalidate your caches and restart android studio

Comment: Actually the file content is empty, nothing to show in the preview. Then I copied some layout xml from internet but still its not showing in the preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android studio, goto `File -> Editor -> File and Code Templates` and make sure you have something like

[image]

If you dont have this, may be you have to **UPDATE/REINSTALL** android studio.

Comment: Yes in my android studio, File and Code Template for layout resource file is empty. from where can I get that template code?

Comment: not sure. But you can try typing this code in picture in that window, and clicking apply

Comment: if you want all those codes, may be i can share it on my github page. Let me know

Comment: may be for now you can share those code snippets. Hope I have to reinstall the android studio. That is the perfect solution.

Comment: I guess thats the only possible solution. Because I tried deleting those templates, and my android studio is still producing valid layouts. So adding those snippets may do no good

Comment: I have shared all xml templates [here](https://github.com/AswinpAshok/Studio-templates). If you want java templates, I can share that too. Not sure it's going to work. I think your installation got corrupt. You may have to uninstall-reinstall android studio.

Answer (score 0):

In android studio, goto File -> Editor -> File and Code Templates ->other add the following codes...

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In valueResourceFile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
</resources>
```

In resourceFile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<${ROOT_TAG} xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</${ROOT_TAG}>
```

In layoutResourceFile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<${ROOT_TAG} xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="${LAYOUT_WIDTH}"
             android:layout_height="${LAYOUT_HEIGHT}">

</${ROOT_TAG}>
```

In layoutResourceFile_vertical.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<${ROOT_TAG} xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="${LAYOUT_WIDTH}"
             android:layout_height="${LAYOUT_HEIGHT}">

</${ROOT_TAG}>
```

In Activity.java

```
package ${PACKAGE_NAME};

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
    public class ${NAME} extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     }
    }
```

In Fragment.java

```
package ${PACKAGE_NAME};

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class ${NAME} extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In Application.java

```
package ${PACKAGE_NAME};

import android.app.Application;


public class ${NAME} extends Application {
}
```

In Service.java

```
package ${PACKAGE_NAME};

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;


public class ${NAME} extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In Broadcast_Receiver.java

```
package ${PACKAGE_NAME};

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ${NAME} extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    }
}
```

In Remote_Interface.aidl

```
package ${PACKAGE_NAME};

interface ${NAME} {
}
```

I hope this will help you...

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written